Is a state machine with a register for return state a good design choice?
I want to design a state machine for one module that has to communicate with another module via a protocol.
Multiple states need might end up needing to communicate, State A, State B, State C. they build the package and the go to the send state. The thing is that once the communication ends they need to return to different states, as they need to process the replied data differently. One possibility is to replicate the communications state Fig 2 or to have a register save the return state, Fig 1 where the communication state will go to the return state depending on what state arrive to it.
I am wondering which is a better design choice, and if they are both awful, then what have people been using? I feel like this is something that is found a lot in design.


it might become more obvious if you draw a complete state machine

Well, the whole concept of subroutines and return registers (or a stack) is a thing in most CPU designs, so it certainly is a common thing to do. After all, a CPU is just a big state machine.
But your question so so vague and generic that it is impossible to see what the tradeoffs might be for your specific situation. For example, if "Communications state" is really just one state, then having a copy of it for each instance would not be out of the question. But if it's really a collection of states, then a return register might make sense.
An alternative design approach would be to move the communications protocol out to its own separate state machine. This would guarantee that you could reduce the communication state to a single state in the main state machine, with a simple handshake between the two state machines.

I think you are confusing what a state machine is. If you are branching out to multiple states, then each state needs a distinct input to advance it to the next state. The state machine can't be in mutiple states at the same time.
So let's say you are in the "comm state", if you want to go to state A, then you would need an input to advance it to state A. Same thing with state B and C, you would need an input or combination of inputs to advance it to those states. Those inputs would need to be a distinctly different or if you tried to realize this it would prioritize one state over the other.

The state machine can't be in mutiple states at the same time. It can be, but that requires a proper UML diagram to show in a way that makes sense. Real-life state machines can be quite complex and there can be quite many states they concurrently are in. See https://www.state-machine.com/fsm, follow the links from there if you want deep immersion :) See also https://www.state-machine.com/hierarchical-state-machines-persevere-on-mars

I guess I'm thinking FSM
